# Disabling Visual Preview in FME 2019?

Tags: fme-form

I like to use old version of FME where only Inspector are used because it is more steady. Visual Preview is too hasty and useless for me because it will always change map view when selecting different FME -transformer.

How to disable Visual Preview in FME Workbench 2019?

There is document from Safe about Visual Preview.

http://docs.safe.com/fme/2019.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Workbench/Workbench/Visual-Preview.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple. Basically use Tools > FME Options > Workbench and turn on the option "Inspect with Data Inspector when Visual Preview window closed"

[image]

Then as long as you have the preview window closed (View > Windows > Visual Preview is the menubar option to do that) then it will act as previous FME versions did.

You can also turn off the effect of the Visual Preview updating each time you click on an object:

[image]

That way you have to specifically click the green cache/inspect button on an object for it to show up in the preview window.